# IEEEtran and pdfpages

Tags: errors, ieeetran, pdfpages

I'm not able to make even this minimal piece of code work when trying to include a pdf file in an IEEEtran document:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{file.pdf}
\end{document}
```

What I get is the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@outputdblcol ...}}\@combinedblfloats \@setmarks
\@outputpage \begingroup \...
```

If I try to replace the document class with a standard one instead (e.g. article) the PDF file is produced with no errors.

Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try to add some text (or `\null`) before `\includepdf` : your issue seems to be caused by `\includepdf` right after `\begin{document}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue seems to be caused by calling `\includepdf` *right after* `\begin{document}`. You can either add some text, or use `\null` to put 'something' without any effect before including your `pdf`:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    \null%
    \includepdf[pages=-]{file.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems to work if you define the offending command if it isn't already defined:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{@setmarks}{\let\@setmarks\relax}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{file.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, which works perfectly too. I simply chose the fastest one.

Comment: Since \@ifundefined macro changed in latest kernel, what about update your answer accordingly?

Comment: @Z.H. oops:-) will fix thanks, done

Comment: By the way, is it a bug of pdfpages? It is OK when I tried pdfpages in an old TeX distribution. And I could not find `\@setmarks` macro in `pdfpages.sty`.

Comment: @Z.H. I suspect so.